# Large margin in table next to image in dreamweaver?

Tags: image, html-table, html-email, margin, dreamweaver

I am VERY new at dreamweaver, and I am making an email to be sent to clients.
However, I am experiencing a lot of odd things like giant spaces in the td where the image is located:

[image]

I don't even know how to describe what it is that it is doing. I hope someone understands what I am talking about and can help me and give me pointers.

I have tried to edit the colspan number and that just moves everything to the right of it:

[image]

Comment: If you able to update your post with some code then someone can help you more. One thing i would point out is dont use row and colspan. It doesnt work well in a few email clients.

Answer (score 0):

HTML emails are a bad place to start with coding HTML as email clients render the HTML very differently. I'd recommend starting with a free template from Campaign Monitor or somewhere and editing it as required. That way you'll see what work-arounds they've used and can replicate them in the future.

Comment: This is for work. My manager assigned me to do this. So i really don't have much of a choice where to start. but thanks.......

Comment: Don't mean to be dismissive, I started with email. Can you provide code examples of where you have problems?

Comment: <td rowspan="2" colspan="5"><img name="header_1" src="images/header_1.gif" width="410" height="157" id="header_1"  /></td>
   
   <td><img name="fb_icon" src="images/fb_icon.gif" width="68" height="47" id="fb_icon"  /></td>

There is a large margin between these where they should be flush. I have a large screenshot of document and html in my question above if that is easier to look at.

Comment: It's likely a problem further up the document like a width not matching the table cells underneath. Is there a width on the first table?
You could try downloading this extension for chrome which has a handy outlining tool that will show all of your table elements http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/
Can't do much more without seeing the whole document I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that!